# scalajs: get the searchParams from window.location (to parse the query string)

Tags: scala.js

`scalajs.dom.window.location` returns a `Location` instance.
URL has a searchParams field.
How I get the `searchParams` from a `Location` instance?

Note: https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js-dom/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/scalajs/dom/experimental/URL.scala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new dom.experimental.URL(dom.window.location.href).searchParams
```

Note that this URL class is just a facade for the [native JS URL class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) provided by the browser platform. While it is widely supported by browsers, Internet Explorer does not support `searchParams`.

Alternatively, you can use java's URL class in a similar manner, or even hand code the parsing of query params.